# How to iterate HTML file and parse specific data to Dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have looked over various methods from `BeautifulSoup` to XML parsers and I think that there must be a simpler way to iterate over an HTML file to parse information into a dataframe table. There is a lot of information with specific section headers:

```
<h2 class="chapter-header-western">CHAPTER 1</h2>
    <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0.08in"><b>1</b>text
    <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0.08in"><b>Header</b></p>
    <p align="left" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0.08in"><b>2</b>text
    </p>
    <p align="left" style="line-height: 120%; margin-left: 0.3in; text-indent: -0.3in; margin-bottom: 0.08in">
    <b>3 </b>text
    </p>
    <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0.08in">text <b>4 </b>text
    <b>5 </b>text<b>6 </b>text
    </p>
```

The html is a bit of a mess being converted from a docx file, but all I need to do is parse each piece of text following the bold numbers `<b>#</b>` into its own row:

| Chapter | Number | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | text |
| 1 | 2 | text |
| 1 | 3 | text |

Perhaps I need to make a tag for `<b>#</b>` as a delineation?

I tried using BeautifulSoup find_all but this only returns strings between tags, and I need a way to return the text **following** a set of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example you could select all `<b>` elements and check if the text `isnumeric()` - Use `find_previous()` and `next_sibling` to select necessary information from left and right:

```
for e in soup.select('b'):
    if e.get_text(strip=True).isnumeric():
        data.append({
            'chapter': e.find_previous('h2').get_text(strip=True).split()[-1],
            'number': e.get_text(strip=True),
            'text': e.next_sibling.strip() if e.next_sibling else None
        })
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<h2 class="chapter-header-western">CHAPTER 1</h2>
    <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0.08in"><b>1</b>text
    <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0.08in"><b>Header</b></p>
    <p align="left" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0.08in"><b>2</b>text
    </p>
    <p align="left" style="line-height: 120%; margin-left: 0.3in; text-indent: -0.3in; margin-bottom: 0.08in">
    <b>3 </b>text
    </p>
    <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0.08in">text <b>4 </b>text
    <b>5 </b>text<b>6 </b>text
    </p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for e in soup.select('b'):
    if e.get_text(strip=True).isnumeric():
        data.append({
            'chapter': e.find_previous('h2').get_text(strip=True).split()[-1],
            'number': e.get_text(strip=True),
            'text': e.next_sibling.strip() if e.next_sibling else None
        })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | chapter | number | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | text |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | text |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | text |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | text |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | text |
| 5 | 1 | 6 | text |